# Cisco Jabber Click-to-call broken with Chrome or Skype

Tags: windows, file-association, cisco-jabber

If I have either Chrome or Skype installed on a computer with Cisco Jabber 9, clicking on a `tel:+15558765309` link pops up a dialog asking if I want to use Chrome or Skype.  If I uninstall Chrome and Skype, the link will work properly, but I cannot seem to set Jabber as the default handler for the `tel:` protocol.

How do I set Jabber as the handler for the `tel:` protocol when it doesn't show up in the menu?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 added deprecated old-style file registrations. An application [must register a `ProgID` and `Capabilities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to advertise a URL handler in Windows 8 and above.

Jason Harmer has a [helpful blog article](http://myucthoughts.blogspot.ca/2013/02/windows-8-chrome-and-lync-2013-client.html) pointing out the specific key needed for Lync, and we can translate and add the missing entries to get it working for Jabber.  Save the below to a `.reg` file, and Jabber will appear in the menu.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Cisco\Jabber (ITP)]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Cisco\Jabber (ITP)\Capabilities]
"TEL"="callto"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Cisco\Jabber (ITP)\Capabilities\UrlAssociations]
"tel"="Cisco.Jabber.ITP.telhandler"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\RegisteredApplications]
"Cisco.Jabber.ITP"="SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Cisco\\Jabber (ITP)\\Capabilities"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Cisco.Jabber.ITP]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Cisco.Jabber.ITP\CLSID]
@="{46B1B0A9-6C89-476A-BD0E-4A83EBC8D644}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Cisco.Jabber.ITP.telhandler]
@="URL:Cisco Jabber Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Cisco.Jabber.ITP.telhandler\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Cisco Systems\\Cisco Jabber\\CiscoJabber.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Cisco.Jabber.ITP.telhandler\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Cisco.Jabber.ITP.telhandler\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Cisco.Jabber.ITP.telhandler\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Cisco Systems\\Cisco Jabber\\CiscoJabber.exe\" -URI %1"
```

[image: Image showing Cisco Jabber in prompt for <code>tel:</code> handler]

---

**Edit:** Cisco Jabber does have problems parsing the `tel:` uri, so it may be helpful to run it through another script before calling jabber.  An example is [posted on Gist](https://gist.github.com/mgaffigan/5978c15f65dd2453c7302d9ef07922d6) and can be compiled with `csc Program.cs`.  Prepend the full path of the compiled executable to the default value of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Cisco.Jabber.ITP.telhandler\shell\open\command` key.